# Automated way to determine function's data scope I must mock for testing?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mocking, integration-testing

I am looking at how to test a function (and its downstream called functions). I would like to ascertain the data objects that the function and its callees access, in order to provide local mock data sources or items for testing. The function receives one object as a parameter; but it or its callees may follow references from this object's properties to obtain other objects, etc.

The work is in VS2012 Premium (with TFS in the background), .NET Framework 4.5, Visual Basic. I'm planning to use the Microsoft testing framework.

Is there any tool or feature that would in the VS2012-TFS world identify and summarize the data universe required by a function and the functions/subs that it calls?

Comment: Short answer: no. Wouldn't use MSTest anyway, there are some frameworks like NUnit and xUnit that do a much better job.